# Is there way to tell CMake to generate several install rules?

Tags: cmake

Using CMake to generate GNU/Makefile as an example, I would like to be able to run different install rules, say `make install` and `make install-doc`.

Is there a way to tell CMake to generate this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom target which invokes the `cmake_install.cmake` script in the outermost binary directory. This script is also invoked when you run the default `install` target.

```
add_custom_target(install-doc
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "-DBUILD_TYPE=$<CONFIGURATION>"
        "-DCOMPONENT=doc" "-P" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```

The desired installation component has to be passed as the CMake variable `COMPONENT`. The build configuration can be set with the variable `BUILD_TYPE`. `$<CONFIGURATION>` is a [generator expression](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) which will be replaced by the currently active build configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. The idea with a separate `make install-doc` is to have the doc not installed with the regular `make install`. Would that work with your solution ?